# TypeScript character type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

My question is very brief. I am new to TypeScript, been searching around here and there but didn't find yet an answer.

Does any experienced TypeScripter know if there is a character Type or an easy way to achieve one?

Comment: [Basic types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: Whats wrong with just a String of length 1?

Comment: @Pointy really? You think I didn't read through that?

Comment: @Pointy Looks like OP is asking for advanced types…

Comment: What purpose/advantage are you looking for with this?

Comment: @cocoseis I just wanted to do some stuff with characters, if there was a straightway to do this without having to check if strings have length === 1.

Comment: @charliebrownie you can use a type guard, if you pass strings through a  function that uses it initially then it's guaranteed to be a char throughout your app (otherwise it will throw at an early stage). Have a look at my answer for the solution

Answer (score 82, accepted):

TypeScript does not have a type for representing fixed-length strings.

Comment: To sort of "extend" the dialog here. Typescript expands on statically typing the native types of javascript. Javascript does not have a char type. So type-script doesn't have a char type.

Comment: If only `string  & { length: 1 }` could be statically inferred... I tried but it throws an error when trying to assign any one-character string to a variable of that type.

Comment: `chars` are types of 8-bit. A type of 8-bits can be represented using an `Uint8Array` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 38):

I'm not sure about *easy*, but you could sorta do something with string literal types:

```
type Char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' | 'j' | 'k' 
| 'l' | 'm' | 'n' | 'o' | 'p' | 'q' | 'r' | 's' | 't' | 'u' | 'v' | 'w' | 'x' 
| 'y' | 'z' | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I' | 'J' | 'K' 
| 'L' | 'M' | 'N' | 'O' | 'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' | 'T' | 'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' 
| 'Y' | 'Z' | '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' // etc....;
```

of course, this is a fairly brittle solution and breaks down when you consider unicode characters, and I wouldn't really suggest it. As Ryan mentions, JavaScript itself doesn't have any notion of a fixed length string, nor the concept of a `char` as distinct from a `string`.

Comment: May work on an individual `Char`, but if you try to use a string, you'll get `Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'Char[]'`.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a regex within TypeGuard to contain it's type eg:(you can declare an empty enum to get a new type to be associated with the type guard)

```ts
enum CharType { }
export type Char = string & CharType
const isChar = (str: string): str is Char => /^(.|\n)$/.test(
    str
)
export function toChar(c: string): Char {
    //you can also use is char here for to test whether actually is char
    if (!isChar(c)) {
        throw new Error('not a char')
    }
    return c
}
```

Now Char matches only things that come from calling char(eg actually casted by calling the function rather than just asserted on build time. The compiler simply accepts that a Char is returned and that's actually true if you think of it since it will just throw otherwise)

Original Source(applied to date string):
[Atomic Object](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/19/strongly-typed-date-string-typescript/)

Assumptions:
I assume that by mentioning typescript you mean a type used for compile-time checks by typescript compiler and not looking for any kind of optimization on the actual compiled js side(since js only has strings)

The only issue I can see is that you can pass whatever to char function  and it will only throw at run time. But you will never reach to a state where you expect a Char and you get something else(since Chars only come from calling char).

On a side note even java casts throw just runtime exceptions.

Although the above approach might not have much to do with casts, I do find some commonalities...

Comment: Typescript is so powerful, If you ever think of a type you can't express you might be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In some comments and answers the lack of a small type of size 8-bit in JavaScript was pointed out. Well, thats not entirely true. With [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)s we can create a type of size similar to a classical `C`-like `char`. Here a quick take by utilizing `Uint8ClampedArray`.

```js
type CharString = '!'|'"'|'#'|'$'|'%'|'&'|"'"|'('|')'|'*'|'+'|','|'-'|'.'|'/'|'0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|':'|';'|'<'|'='|'>'|'?'|'@'|'A'|'B'|'C'|'D'|'E'|'F'|'G'|'H'|'I'|'J'|'K'|'L'|'M'|'N'|'O'|'P'|'Q'|'R'|'S'|'T'|'U'|'V'|'W'|'X'|'Y'|'Z'|'['|'\\'|']'|'^'|'_'|'`'|'a'|'b'|'c'|'d'|'e'|'f'|'g'|'h'|'i'|'j'|'k'|'l'|'m'|'n'|'o'|'p'|'q'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u'|'v'|'w'|'x'|'y'|'z'|'{'|'|'|'}'|'~';

type CharNumber = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|150|151|152|153|154|155|156|157|158|159|160|161|162|163|164|165|166|167|168|169|170|171|172|173|174|175|176|177|178|179|180|181|182|183|184|185|186|187|188|189|190|191|192|193|194|195|196|197|198|199|200|201|202|203|204|205|206|207|208|209|210|211|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|220|221|222|223|224|225|226|227|228|229|230|231|232|233|234|235|236|237|238|239|240|241|242|243|244|245|246|247|248|249|250|251|252|253|254|255;

class Char extends Uint8ClampedArray {
  constructor(char: CharNumber | CharString | Char) {
    super(1);
    this.setValue(char);
  }

  get _value(): CharNumber {
    return this[0] as CharNumber;
  }
  set _value(char: CharNumber | CharString | Char) {
    if (char instanceof Char) {
      this[0] = char._value;
    } else if (typeof char === 'number') {
      this[0] = char;
    } else if (typeof char === 'string') {
      this[0] = char.charCodeAt(0);
    }
  }

  setValue(char: CharNumber | CharString | Char) {
    this._value = char;
  }

  toString(): CharString {
    return String.fromCharCode(this._value) as CharString;
  }

  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint === 'number') {
      return this.toNumber();
    }
    return this.toString();
  }

  toNumber(): CharNumber {
    return this._value;
  }
}

function char(c: CharNumber | CharString | Char) {
  return new Char(c);
}

const messageInChars = [
  char(72),
  char(101),
  char(108),
  char(108),
  char(111),
  char(32),
  char(83),
  char(116),
  char(97),
  char(99),
  char(107),
  char(79),
  char(118),
  char(101),
  char(114),
  char(102),
  char(108),
  char(111),
  char(119),
];

console.log('char array as string:', messageInChars.join(''));
console.log('calculating with chars:', +messageInChars[0] + +messageInChars[1]);
```

**Thoughts:**

In the example, I am using `numbers` to initialize the `Char`s. As `numbers` are `doubles`, for the short moment of initialization I assume more memory is needed, but not at rest.

Further, I am not entirely sure what extending a `TypedArray` does to its instance's size.

---

**old answer**

A Char is simply a number. Since the basic types of TypeScript do not include Chars what you could do is store a number and convert it back and forth:

```
var number = "h".charCodeAt(0);
var char = String.fromCharCode(number)
```

And to something like:

```
class Char {
    private _value:Number;
    
    constructor(char: Number | String){
        this.setValue(char);
    }
    
    get getValue():String {
        return String.fromCharCode(this._value);
    }
    set setValue(char: Number | String) {
          if (typeof char === "number") {
              this._value = char;
          }
          else {
            this._value = char.charCodeAt(0);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's not *any* number, it's an unsigned 16 bit integer at least.

Comment: so, how does that matter?

Comment: It matters because it means we cannot use the builtin `number` type

Comment: Note that Number is a floating point value of undefined length. Do not expect better performance.

Comment: While it's a bit late, you may also want to override `toString()` so that it concatenate properly with other strings

Comment: I have added an update using 8-bits.

Answer (score 3):

As I know, the basic types of typescript don't include char.

Answer (score 3):

As a slightly more concise method than [listing out *all*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679069) letter characters, you can list out all upper-case or all lower-case characters, then use [`Lowercase`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) or `Uppercase` to change their capitalization and unify with the previous type.

```
type UpperCaseCharacter = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I' | 'J' | 'K' | 'L' | 'M' | 'N' | 'O' | 'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' | 'T' | 'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' | 'Y' | 'Z';
// add additional non-letter characters to this union as desired
type Character = UpperCaseCharacter | Lowercase<UpperCaseCharacter>;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to define a type for a single character string when you are in the context of a function with generics and **you know the length of the variable you want to test against**.

```js
// this is a utility type for our purposes:
type OnlyFirstChar<S extends string> = S extends `${infer $TFirstChar}${string}`
  ? $TFirstChar
  : string;
// this is the type you are after:
type SingleChar<S extends string> = S extends S & OnlyFirstChar<S>
  ? S & OnlyFirstChar<S>
  : string & { length: 1 };

const fn = <S extends string>(singleChar: SingleChar<S>): string => {
  //...
};
```

When I say "**you know the length of the variable you want to test against**" I refer to literal string *(`"something"`)* or object with constant values like `const obj = { a: "stringval"} as const`. If you you don't know the length of the string you want to pass in you can't really check agains it ️

Thanks to @samthecodingman from the comments you even get a helpful TS error message:

[image: example of ts error in code editor]

Comment: While the type can never resolve, you can abuse that fact to make the linting error more helpful: `type SingleChar<S extends string> = S extends (S & OnlyFirstChar<S>) ? (S & OnlyFirstChar<S>) : (string & { length: 1 })`. Unfortunately this seems to only throw a warning when using constants or hardcoded arguments like in your example, `string` type arguments are still permitted.

Comment: @samthecodingman you are right, it doesn't work if you pass just a variable of type string. But I don't imagine any possible type system to be able to do that. A variable of type `string` can be of any length. I think the question of this thread can only be answered if the variable has a known length which is the case with literals and constants.

I will update my answer with this info ️

Answer (score 1):

You could just define a wrapper around `string`, and throw an error if the string is more than one character.

```
class Character {
    readonly char: string;
    constructor(char: string) {
        if(char.length !== 1) {
           throw new Error(char + " is not a single character");
        }
    
        this.char = char;
    }
    
    toString(): string {
       return this.char;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////
var good: Character = new Character("f");
var bad: Character = new Character("foo"); //error
```

Of course, you can also add helper methods to the class which operate on the string like `toLowerCase()`, `toUpperCase()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Char<Type extends string> = Type extends `${infer FirstChar}${infer Rest}`
  ? Rest extends ''
    ? Type
    : never
  : never;

function char<Type extends string>(char : Char<Type>) {

}

char('') // error
char('a') // okay
char('aa') // error
```