# How to override VSCode tooltip for TypeScript type alias?

Tags: string, typescript, visual-studio-code, types, char

The following code doesn't work:

```js
type char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f';
const s: string = 'foo';
const [c]: char = s;
// [ERROR]: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'char'.
```

I could do this instead:

```js
type char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | string;
```

But that causes 2 problems:

1. When I hover over a `char` variable, the tooltip says it's type `string` not `char` (I'm in VSCode). I know I don't have the `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` etc... in the screenshot, but pretend I do, because tooltip is the same.

   [image: tooltip]
2. I won't get warned if I try to do something like `const letter: char = 'notachar'`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript character type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678891/typescript-character-type)

Comment: It does not answer my question because even if there's no way for TypeScript to enforce my `char` type, I would accept an answer that shows me how to fix the tooltip.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678891/typescript-character-type

Comment: My question is also about the VSCode tooltip.

Comment: I changed the title to reflect this.

Comment: If you say `char` is `string` then it will always be `string`. If you want it to be custom, you will need to provide a custom type or union e.g. `type char = 'a' | 'b'`.

Comment: If I do that, this throws: `const [foo]: char = 'bar';` because type `string` can't be assigned to type `char`.

Comment: Which is exactly what you want? You cannot assign a `string` to a `char`, in any language that supports `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to override VSCode tooltip for TypeScript type alias?

When you have a union that resolves to something simpler, *TypeScript will always show the simpler version*

Example:

```
type char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | string;
// resolves to the following simpler type so that is what TypeScript will show. 
type char = string;
```

Comment: That's depressing but you get best answer unless someone finds a way.